# What is the meaning of 'without' in the phrase "was willing to live with him without"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

The context involves a woman in love with an abusive man. We are told of this relationship that:

> As he drank and was of a violent character, she did not want to marry
>   him, but was willing to live with him **without**.

- “About Love.” In Anton Chekhov's Selected Stories. New York: W.W. Norton & Company, 2014.

It seems '**without**' is short for '**without marriage**'. If so, how can we explain this usage? What warrants the apparent ellipsis here?

Comment: Perhaps only the fact that Chekhov is so famous that the translator (Garnett) can get away with it. The translation _is_ over 100 years old. // Perhaps the 'intransitive adposition' is being anticipated. 'Without' perhaps meaning 'outside the house' ... 'in the doghouse'? Or as you guess, the metaphorical extension.

Comment: It would be useful if some native speakers of Russian could give their opinion by comparing the original version with its translation.

Comment: (a) At least outside of CGEL and similar treatments, 'adposition' is the blanket term, the hypernym,  for prepositions and postpositions (there is the odd postposition in English [eg '_I gave up smoking many years _ago_' / 'The drop in daily deaths _notwithstanding_, we must continue to socially distance']). (b) Many grammarians accept the English word subclass 'intransitive preposition' nowadays. (c) I seem to remember that 'without' in its archaic meaning 'outside' could be used after, as well as before, the noun group. So 'without' might be seen as a relict of 'the walls without', say.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I've found the original text in Russian.
The original text says, "she didn't want to marry him, however she didn't mind **living this way**", ie. **without changes**.

Hope it helped.

Comment: This then suggests the possible meaning of **'nevertheless'** or **'regardless'**. Perhaps this is what is meant by **'without'**.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of the ellipsis is:

*... she did not want to marry him, but was willing to live with him without doing so.*

Comment: This interpretation leads to a conflict between the use of the negative in the first clause and the conjunction **'but'** joining the second clause. If she didn't want to live with him, then the second clause should be joined with **'and'**, not **'but'**.

Answer (score 0):

There is a somewhat archaic use of "without" to mean "outside". It could be that the sentence implies a readiness to live "outside" marriage so to speak

Comment: Yes, I know of that meaning. But the ellipsis remains.